# Side bar isn't fixed

Tags: javascript, wordpress, wordpress-theming, sidebar

first of all this is the website I am talking about:
[Be Better You.net](http://bebetteryou.net/)

Everything up to here is awesome, the problem is when I click on one of the categories in the right side bar. I get to a new page for e.g. [This Page](http://bebetteryou.net/%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%93%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9A-%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%9D-%D7%9C%D7%A2%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%99%D7%94-%D7%91%D7%9E%D7%A1%D7%AA-%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%A8/), and the problem is that the side-bar isn't fixed as it is on the front page. ( it's somewhat relative to the post's length)

I've tried for over 2 hours editing the style.css file, but no luck.
[Style.css code](http://pastebin.com/uXkgaUuj)

Comment: Your site using js for changing position. Please check your js files.

Comment: @LemonKazi Here's my functions.js code: http://pastebin.com/59w1uGTm

Comment: I sow that now your site working well. Can you share with me how you fixed that.

Comment: @LemonKazi It's not fixed yet. Still the same problem. (I didn't touch anything since I posted this post)

Comment: oh I got your problem. If you visit last post page from home->single post. it's working properly. But if without loading home page visit single post page it's not working. sometime in my side it's working for both. critical problem. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit this code in your functions.js

```
function scroll() {
           // var windowPos = $window.scrollTop();
           var windowPos = $('body').scrollTop();
```

**or use this variable**

```
var windowPos = $('html').scrollTop();
```

Comment: Thanks for ur answer, but no luck yet. It didn't work. I tried both 'body' and 'html'.